# Query WCF Data Service in Command-line Console

Tags: .net, wcf

I need to write a command-line script to query a WCF data service. Is there an approach I can achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but assume you could use CURL to write a request to said service. If you're on the windows stack i suggest using cygwin and make sure you install the CURL library as part of the initial setup...